# I'm trying to make a rock, paper, scissors and it keeps outputting none, if its a tie it will output correctly. So why is it outputting none?

Tags: python-3.x

I don't understand what is going on here, I haven't coded very much, I have done other coding projects and I figured them out. I tried elif and else but those keep saying syntax error even though I can see other peoples code work with them.

```
import random

def play():
       user = input("What's your choice? rock, paper, scissors\n")
       computer = random.choice("rock', 'paper', 'scissors")

       if user == computer:
           print('Its a tie')
        

def is_win(player, opponent):
    if (player == 'rock' and opponent == 'scissors') or (player == 'scissors' and opponent == 'paper') or (player == 'rock' and opponent == 'paper'):
        print('You won!')

def is_lose(player, opponent):
    if (player == 'paper' and opponent == 'rock') or (player == 'scissors' and opponent == 'rock') or (player == 'paper' and opponent == 'scissors'):
        print('you lost!')
print(play())
```

Comment: You never call `is_win()` or `is_lose()`.

Comment: Also, those 2 functions should probably `return True` or `return False`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so after someone edited my code, I still saw errors within the code so I fixed it. one error being that the opponent could not have rock. So here is the finished code.

```
import random

def play():
       player = input("What's your choice? rock, paper, scissors\n")
       computer = random.choice(['rock', 'paper', 'scissors'])

       if player == computer:
           print('Its a tie')
       elif (player == 'rock' and computer == 'scissors') or (player == 'scissors' and computer == 'paper') or (player == 'paper' and computer == 'rock'):
           print('You won!')
       else:
           print('You lost!')
play(play())
```

Comment: Is there a way I can loop the program?

Comment: Yes, call `play() inside the `play` function.

Answer (score 0):

Issues are with quotes and there is no call to `is_win` and `is_lose`. Please be consistent with quotes.

```
import random

def play():
       user = input("What's your choice? rock, paper, scissors\n")
       computer = random.choice(['rock', 'paper', 'scissors'])

       if user == computer:
           print('Its a tie')
       elif (player == 'rock' and opponent == 'scissors') or (player == 'scissors' and opponent == 'paper') or (player == 'rock' and opponent == 'paper'):
           print('You won!')
       else:
           print('you lost!')
play()
```

Comment: You don't need that call to `print` at the bottom. Change `print(play())` to just `play()`.

Comment: Notice `random.choice` should take arguments in list

Comment: "Notice random.choice should take arguments in list". Sorry but that made no sense to me

Comment: Ok so now I have fixed the code but if I keep typing rock it will either show up as tie or win. It won't show up as lose.

Comment: Here's your problem: ` or (player == 'rock' and opponent == 'paper')`. Rock doesn't beat paper.